# bash error "date: invalid date `24/06/2013 21:22'" with Debian but not with RHEL?

Tags: bash, debian, kerberos, klist

I am using a script that creates two variables based on what it finds in any given Kerberos ticket.  The kerberos ticket, referenced as $TCACHE, would look like this ... :

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_12345_gbiRMw
Default principal: testuser@TEST.SITE

Valid starting    Expires           Service principal
24/06/2013 11:22  24/06/2013 21:22  krbtgt/TEST.SITE@TEST.SITE
        renew until 01/07/2013 11:22
```

... and the variables in question like this ... :

```
EXPIRE_TIME=$( date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 krbtgt | awk '{print $3, $4}' )" +%s )
RENEW_TIME=$( date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 "renew until" | awk '{print $3, $4}' )" +%s )
```

Both of these work normally under RHEL 5 and 6 ... :

**EXPIRE_TIME**:

```
# date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 krbtgt | awk '{print $3, $4}' )" +%s             
1372122061
#  date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 krbtgt | awk '{print $3, $4}' )"
Mon Jun 24 21:01:01 EDT 2013
# klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 krbtgt | awk '{print $3, $4}'             
06/24/13 21:01:01
```

**RENEW_TIME**:

```
# date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 "renew until" | awk '{print $3, $4}' )" +%s 
1372046400
# klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 "renew until" | awk '{print $3, $4}'
07/01/13 08:24:15
# klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 "renew until" | awk '{print $3, $4}'
07/01/13 08:24:15
```

Under Debian 7, however, I get this instead ... :

**EXPIRE_TIME**:

```
# date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 krbtgt | awk '{print $3, $4}' )" +%s
date: invalid date `24/06/2013 21:22'
# date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 krbtgt | awk '{print $3, $4}' )"
date: invalid date `24/06/2013 21:22'
# klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 krbtgt | awk '{print $3, $4}'            
24/06/2013 21:22
```

**RENEW_TIME**:

```
# date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 "renew until" | awk '{print $3, $4}' )" +%s
1357575720
# date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 "renew until" | awk '{print $3, $4}' )"      
Mon Jan  7 11:22:00 EST 2013
# klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 "renew until" | awk '{print $3, $4}'            
01/07/2013 11:22
```

For reference, here's the output of just the date command on each server ... :

**RHEL 6**:

```
# date
Mon Jun 24 12:29:06 EDT 2013
```

**DEBIAN 7**:

```
# date
Mon Jun 24 12:29:18 EDT 2013
```

Can anyone explain and help me understand how to mitigate this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**:  I found this bug report that describes the issue perfectly:  http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=697954

... so I guess I'm not going crazy after all.

**UPDATE 2**:  I installed krb5-user 1.11 from experimental and, as advertised, the problem went away.

Comment: Hmm, the one difference I see is that the `klist` on Debian gives a four-byte year (2013) while `klist` on RedHat gives a two-byte year (13). Is that something you expect?

Comment: Also, I wonder if there's a difference in American vs. European date representation. `07/01/13` is valid in both America and Europe, while `24/06/2013` can only be European. So if your `date` command expects an American format, that would definitely be a problem.

Comment: @chrisaycock - I actually hadn't noticed that.  Not sure it would make a difference, though.  My confusion is in why, on Debian, the two seemingly identical commands (one looks at krbtgt and the other "renew until") don't produce the same output.  I also wondered if it was a date format issue as well; like you say regarding European versus US dates.  I'm not sure how to tell what Debian is using in that regard.  Now that I think about it more, I suspect that is probably the most likely case.

Comment: @chrisaycock - Took me a second but I remembered the locale command and "LC_TIME" for both the RHEL6 and Debian7 server are set to "LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"".

Comment: So your `date` command wants an American date and you've given it a European one. Sounds like we've found the problem.

Comment: @chrisaycock - Doubtful, all three date fields in the Kerberos ticket on the Debian server are in DD/MM/YYYY format.  The "Expires" value fails to convert to seconds but the "renew until" field converts normally.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the `date` command, not anything related to bash. You should be able to narrow it down a bit by just showing the output of `date -d '24/06/2013 21:22'` on each system. Note that the `DD/MM/YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY` formats are ambiguous; you can't tell whether `11/12/2013` is December 11 or November 12, and some software might choose not to try to guess. It might be partly a matter of locale settings. Suggestion: convert the dates to [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) `YYYY-MM-DD` format before feeding them to `date`.

Comment: Is that datestring actually parsed by `date` on rhel?  Or is `klist` formatting the date differently?

Comment: It seems that klist is formatting the dates on RHEL as MM/DD/YY (and conversion works) whereas Debian klist presents them as DD/MM/YYYY and it works on the "renew until" date but fails on krbtgt one.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to how `date` command parse the date in different platforms.

- In Debian it is parsing as MM/DD/YYYY.
- In RHEL it is parsing as DD/MM/YYYY.

This is done by design. Hardcoded in the source code if you want to know.  In [parse-datetime.y](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/parse-datetime.y) source, you can read the following:

> Interpret as YYYY/MM/DD if the first value has 4 or more digits,
>   otherwise as MM/DD/YY. The goal in recognizing YYYY/MM/DD is solely to
>   support legacy machine-generated dates like those in an RCS log
>   listing.  If you want portability, use the ISO 8601 format.

In general, parsing strings **should always be treated as unsafe**: there is no guarantee that this type of code will always work.  So the best you can do is to adapt the date you read to ISO 8601 before send it to date command. This can be done with Regex.

So here is your *portable* code:

```
EXPIRE_TIME=$( date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 krbtgt | awk '{print $3, $4}' | sed -r 's#([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)#\3-\2-\1#g' )" +%s )
RENEW_TIME=$( date -d "$( klist -c $TCACHE | grep -m1 "renew until" | awk '{print $3, $4}' | sed -r 's#([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)#\3-\2-\1#g' )" +%s )
```

If you are interested to check, via code, the format expected by `date` you can test with a known conflicting date:

```
# Try to parse a known conflicting date
date -d "30/01/2010" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null

# Test Exit Code
if [ $? ]; then
  # Returned error, so the expected format is MM/DD/YYYY
else
  # No error, so the expected format is DD/MM/YYYY
fi
```